# Return Record as text

Tags: postgresql, return, record

I have the following on a postgres function:

```
ret_feedback RECORD;
t_query_feedback = 
        'SELECT
        company,
        country,
        vendor,
        FROM 
        mytable
        limit 100
        execute t_query_feedback into ret_feedback;
        return ret_feedback.company;
```

It works for "company" but it just returns the first row, how can I return them all?
Also, what's the best way to return the whole table from the query above? At a later stage I would need to send an email with the contents of this table.

Thanks,

Comment: A `record` variable can hold only a single row. You'll have to return a complete query result.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING